# Run method from another method - Java

Tags: java, netbeans, tooltip

I want a message to display in the toolbar when the timer runs out.
Here is my code:

```
private void startJButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     

        Timer oneHour = new Timer(3600000, //RunTheActionPerformedShownBelow);

} 

public void ReminderTrayIco() {

item3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            trayIcon.displayMessage("Title", "Message", TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR);
        }
    });
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to run the code that is under 'item2.addActionListener' when the timer reaches 0. I feel as if there is a very simple solution right under my nose, but I just can't figure it out.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Write a seperate `ActionListener` class which both the `Timer` and `item3` can use. Remember, `Timer` will repeat unless you configure it do to other wise

Comment: I get the error that "void type is not allowed here" should I change the public void to a public String?

Comment: Maybe you need to have a read of [How to write an action listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by writing a custom `ActionListener` class which performs the required operation...

```
public class TrayMessageActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private TrayIcon trayIcon;

    public TrayMessageActionListener(TrayIcon trayIcon) {
        this.trayIcon = trayIcon;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        trayIcon.displayMessage("Title", "Message", TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR);
    }

}
```

Now you can use it with `item3`...

```
item3.addActionListener(new TrayMessageActionListener(trayIcon));
```

and the timer...

```
Timer oneHour = new Timer(3600000, new TrayMessageActionListener(trayIcon));
oneHour.setRepeats(false);
```

This, obviously means that both `item3` and the `Timer` code will need to have access to the same instance of `TrayIcon` when they are created